# Apply JQuery code to multiple elements individually with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using this code to toggle a class (.sticky) on an element with the .container class.

The class is toggled when the top or bottom of the element reaches the top of the viewport.

The code works fine if only one element has the .container class but obviously does not work when there are multiple elements with this class.

How can I rework the code so it will be applied to multiple elements individually when they each reach the top of the viewport? I think I will have to use $(this) in some way but have been unable to make it work so far.

```
var triggerTop = $(".container").offset().top;
var triggerBottom = triggerTop + $(".container").height();
var item = $(".container");

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   var isSticky = currentScroll > triggerTop && currentScroll < triggerBottom
   item.toggleClass('sticky', isSticky);
});
```

Comment: Consider using [position:sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: The classes in `toggleClass()` should be delimited with a space, not a comma. Also, it would *really* help to see a working example. Could you please edit the question to include all relevant code, including the HTML and CSS, in a snippet.

Comment: First you need to correct this: `item.toggleClass('sticky, isSticky);`. It should be: `item.toggleClass('sticky', isSticky);`

Comment: sorry that was just a typo, it's corrected now. The code works fine at the moment with a single element but needs to be tweaked to work on each element with the .container class

Comment: If you're set on taking this root and have multiple .container, then you'll need to store the triggerTop/Bottom on the element itself, eg something like `$(".container").each((i,e) { $(e).data("triggerTop", $(this).offset().top); ... })` then loop through each one within the scroll function.

Comment: just to add the .sticky class should only be added/removed from an element with .container if that specific element reaches the top of the viewport. It should be applied to one element at a time.

Comment: Would suggest as you scroll, you search for visible element and then get it's `top` value. This way you can then take action as each one comes into view.